# How to create pointer to element of a C++ array

Tags: c++

I tried:

```
    rs2::device* dev = &devices[device_idx];
```

but got:

```
/root/realsense_docker/realsense/realsense_multicam.cpp:349:51: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
             rs2::device* dev = &devices[device_idx];
```

code here (slightly different): https://gist.github.com/richardrl/224eb53d4bc1cedda36f5bda1d78ca18#file-realsense_multicam-cpp-L343

Comment: The *real* code is not "slightly different" it's not even close. The real code does, per the link at line 343, `rs2::device dev = ctx.query_devices()[device_idx];` which is viable. `query_devices` returns a container by value, which results in a temporary, but is indexable to make a *copy* of the device at `device_idx` and store it in `dev`, before the temporary container expires.

Comment: *How to create pointer to element of a C++ array* -- I don't see anywhere in that line of code you posted that concludes that `devices` is an array.  Using `[]` does not conclude that the type is an array.  It could be a `std::map` for all we know.

Comment: "_code here (slightly different)_" - no, please, code **here** in a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

> How to create pointer to element of a C++ array

Here are two ways. You can either use the subscript operator and addressof operator, or you can use the addition operator. Example:

```
int array[4];
std::size_t index = 2;
int* ptr1 = &array[index];
int* ptr2 = array + index;
assert(ptr1 == ptr2);
```

---

> ```
> &devices[device_idx];
> ```
>
> but got: error: taking address of temporary

We can deduce that `devices` is not an array.

Comment: It is an array. it is type rs2::device_list according to realsense documentation

Comment: @user3180 And that actually means what? `rs2::device_list` probably isn't an array.

Comment: By documentation http://docs.ros.org/en/kinetic/api/librealsense2/html/classrs2_1_1device__list.html it is a class and its operator[] returns device by value. So applying & to that is taking address of temporary device not making pointer to array element.

Comment: @user3180 `"It is an array" ... "it is type rs2::device_list"` So which one is it? Is the type an array or is the type `rs2::device_list`?